# JOIN tables in wordpress plugin

Tags: mysql, wordpress, join

I'm writing a vote system plugin for wordpress and I have used sql query for setup tables in mysql database but I don't know how I can join tables with `q_ID`.

This is my query:

```
$create_vote_items = ("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {$table_prefix}vote_items(
        ID int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
        content VARCHAR(1000),
        created DATETIME,
        q_ID int(10),
        vote int(10),
        PRIMARY KEY(ID)) CHARSET=utf8
");

$create_vote_questions = ("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {$table_prefix}vote_questions(
        ID int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
        content VARCHAR(1000),
        created DATETIME,
        status tinyint(1),
        PRIMARY KEY(ID)) CHARSET=utf8
");
```

What should I do?

Comment: Maybe start reading up on SQL join tables?
Post what you have tried already and where you got stuck.

Comment: I haven't tried something.. I am starter in this case and dont know what to do

Comment: I would recommend you read some tutorials first and try it out and then when you get stuck, you can post where you got stuck and we can help you. StackOverflow is meant for us to help, not do the work for you.

Comment: You should be learning mysql http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly how you build your tables and initialize them, But by having a landscape from your question, If you wanna join these two tables, You should use `ID` from `vote_questions` and `q_ID` from `vote_items`. So try this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM vote_items INNER JOIN vote_questions 
     ON vote_items.q_ID = vote_questions.ID
```

I would recommend you to google mysql and study tutorials about it.